# Homebrew system need help with probability in any dice

Tags: anydice

I am not much of a programmer.  While I have figured out how to do basic things with *anydice*, I am having trouble figuring out the *least probability of successes needed* for a difficulty number from  2-10  for 1 to 15 dice using D10s.

The system basics are:

- It uses a D10 dice pool system
- Your success check is based on your attribute score
- Your skill determines the number of dice you get to roll
- If a 10 is rolled it counts as 2 successes.

I need a code that determines the *least number of successes needed* at any difficulty of 2-10 using between 1d10 to 15d10 dice. (Any time a 10 is rolled it would count as 2 successes).

I saw the code below for World of Darkness.  It almost works for what I want, but instead of exploding dice on a D10 score of 10, I need the 10 to count as 2 successes.  If anyone can help me modify the code to achieve that output it would be great.

```
function: nwod R:n again N:n {
  if N >= R { result: 1 + [nwod R again d10] }
  result: N >= 8
}

NWOD: [nwod 10 again d10]

loop N over {1..10} {
  output [lowest of 10 and NdNWOD] named "[N]d"
}
```

Comment: What probability do you need? A single success, or formula for n successes, or formula for *at least* n successes?

Comment: Ya sorry I realized I did that late I am wanting a fomular or code  that determines the least number of successes needed at any difficulty of 2-10 rolling  between 1d10 to 10d10 dice. ' Any time a 10 is rolled it would count as 2 successes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following the example I made your [Anydice](http://anydice.com/program/92c8) for all possible skills, and a fixed attribute of 8. In case you want to change the attribute just change the 8 in the code for whatever value it should be.

```
function: successes in S:s {
result: (S >= 8) + (S = 10)
}

loop N over {1..10} {
output [successes in Nd10] named "[N]d"
}
```

Comment: yup that works thanks Albert I also updated what i was asking as it was late at night and not clear at all. Thanks for figuring it out for me

Answer (score 2):

The efficient way to handle such things in AnyDice is to define a custom die that directly gives the number of successes for each die rolled.  For example, for a target difficulty number of 8 or above, you can use `Nd{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2}` (or, more compactly, `Nd{0:7, 1:2, 2}`) to get the number of successes from [rolling *N*d10 vs 8](http://anydice.com/program/a1fe).

The `d{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2}` is simply a custom d10 with its sides relabeled, so that sides 1 to 7 will count as 0, sides 8 and 9 will count as 1, and side 10 will count as 2.

With a little bit of math, you can pretty easily define such custom dice for any difficulty target.  Specifically, for a target value 1 ≤ *T* ≤ 10, there are *T*−1 ways to roll under *T* on a d10, 10−T ways to roll between T and 9 inclusive, and, of course, one way to roll a perfect 10.  Thus, the custom die that gives the number of successes against the target *T* will be `d{0:(T-1), 1:(10-T), 2}`.

[Here's an AnyDice program](http://anydice.com/program/a1ff) that plots the number of successes for any target number 1 ≤ *T* ≤ 10 and any dice pool size 1 ≤ *N* ≤ 15:

```
loop T over {1..10} {
  loop N over {1..15} {
    output Nd{0:(T-1), 1:(10-T), 2} named "[N]d10 vs. [T], double success on 10"
  }
}
```