# How does Halfling Luck affect the probability of surviving my death saves?

Tags: dnd-5e, saving-throw, statistics, character-death, halfling

The probability of a mere human surviving a series of unmodified death saving throws [has been established as 59.5125%.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/76958/what-is-the-probability-of-surviving-my-death-saves) But Halfling Luck [applies to death saving throws](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/78944/does-halfling-luck-apply-to-death-saving-throws) in a dramatic way: A roll of 1 on a death save normally counts as two failures, but halflings are much less likely to suffer this result.

Previous [work in the field of calculating the effects of Halfling Luck](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/100035/21763) does not apply *directly* to death saving throws, because of this asymmetry between races concerning how terrible it is to roll a 1.

How much more likely is it that a halfling will survive a series of death saving throws as opposed to one of those poor unfortunate nonhalflings?

Comment: Besides following naturally from existing questions, this issue has real-world applications as I try to figure out how much of a discount halflings should get on their resurrection insurance premiums.

Comment: You don't even have to be a halfling--the Lucky feat would seriously wreak havoc with the attached question's numbers =)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## A Halfling has a 67.877607328% to survive their death saves

Refer to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/100035/how-does-halfling-luck-re-rolling-my-nat-1s-affect-my-dice-outcome) for calculations of the distribution.

In brief, to re-roll at all, you need to roll a 1 first. The chances of that are \$\frac{1}{20}\$ out of the gate. Once you do re-roll, you have a \$\frac{1}{20}\$ chance of re-rolling any specific number. So the chance of re-rolling *and* getting any specific number is \$\frac{1^2}{20^2} = \frac{1}{400} = 0.25\%\$.

To roll a 1, you *must* re-roll *and* get a 1 on that re-roll. The chances of that is already given, \$0.25\%\$. To roll anything other than a 1, you can get there by two ways: you can roll it the first try (\$5\%\$ chance), or roll a 1 on the first try and get it on the re-roll (\$0.25\%\$ chance). Together, both give you a \$5.25\%\$ chance to roll anything not a 1.

## Solution

To get the answer, you need only to manipulate the probabilities nitsua60 wrote down in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/76958/what-is-the-probability-of-surviving-my-death-saves).

You survive your death saves if:

- You roll a 20 the first time;

$$Pr(X=20) = 5.25\%$$

- You roll below a 20 the first roll, and a 20 the second roll;

$$Pr(X<20) \times Pr(X=20) = (1 - Pr(X=20)) \times Pr(X=20) = 4.974375\%$$

- You roll between a 10 and 19 on all three rolls;

$$Pr(10<X<19)^3 = (0.525)^3 = 14.4703125\%$$

- You roll a 1 the first roll, between a 10 and 19 the second, and a 20 the third roll (and count this twice for symmetry of the first two rolls);

$$2 \times Pr(X=1) \times Pr(10<X<19) \times Pr(X=20)$$

$$2 \times 0.0025 \times 0.525 \times 0.0525 = 0.01378125\%$$

- You roll between a 2 and 19 the first two rolls, but get a 20 the third roll

$$Pr(2<X<19)^2 \times Pr(X=20) = 0.945^2 \times 0.0525 = 4.68838125\%$$

- You roll between a 10 and 19 on the first two rolls, you roll between a 1 and 9 on the third, and between a 10 and 20 on the fourth (count this thrice for symmetry);

$$3 \times Pr(10<X<19)^2 \times Pr(1<X<9) \times Pr(10<X<20)$$

$$3 \times (0.525)^2 \times 0.4225 \times 0.5775 = 20.175233203\%$$

- You roll between a 2 and 9 on the first two rolls, between a 10 and 19 on the third, and a 20 on the fourth one (count this thrice for symmetry);

$$3 \times Pr(2<X<9)^2 \times Pr(10<X<19) \times Pr(X=20)$$

$$3 \times (0.42)^2 \times 0.525 \times 0.0525 = 1.4586075\%$$

- You roll between a 2 and 9 the first two rolls, between a 10 and 19 the next two rolls, and between a 10 and 20 on the fifth roll (and count this six times for symmetry);

$$6 \times Pr(2<X<9)^2 \times Pr(10<X<19)^2 \times Pr(10<X<20)$$

$$6 \times (0.42)^2 \times (0.525)^2 \times (0.5775) = 16.846916625\%$$

Summing up.

$$5.25\% + 4.974375\% + 14.4703125\% + 0.01378125\% + 4.68838125\% + 20.175233203\% + 1.4586075\% + 16.846916625\% = 67.877607328\%$$

---

## Halfling vs Non-Halfing

As a Halfling, your overall chance to survive jumps from ~60% to ~68%. But this massive increase in probability to survive comes from the fact that there are so many ways to survive a death save already, and almost all of those ways to survive (specifically, the ones that don't involve you rolling a Nat 1) gain some small boost in probability. All those small boosts turn out to add up to a large increase.

Comment: The "+2 to death saves" bit has me curious. Are you just approximating the 10% difference in outcome-probability by the flat +2, or did you actually run the probabilities and find that (d20+2) worked out close to (d20 reroll 1)?

Comment: @nitsua60 I approximated. That is a good point, a true +2 would be an entirely different calculation.

Comment: I think I've spotted a tiny typo. \$Pr(1<X<9) = 0.4225\$, not \$0.475\$, giving \$20.175233203124996\%\$ not \$22.682214843\%\$ and a final answer of \$67.877607328125\%\$

Answer (score 2):

Starting with 0 successes and 0 failures, the chance of a halfling surviving is 67.9%. You can compute this figure using this recursive function in python.

```
def chance_survival(f, s):
    chance_crit_fail = 1/20 * 1/20
    chance_norm_fail = 1/20 * 8/20 + 8/20
    chance_norm_succ = 1/20 * 10/20 + 10/20
    chance_crit_succ = 1/20 * 1/20 + 1/20
    if f >= 3:
        return 0
    elif s >= 3:
        return 1
    else:
        return (
            chance_crit_fail * chance_survival(f + 2, s) +
            chance_norm_fail * chance_survival(f + 1, s) +
            chance_norm_succ * chance_survival(f, s + 1) +
            chance_crit_succ * chance_survival(f, s + 3)
        )
```

For reference, using similar code, you can compute that the chance of someone without the lucky trait surviving is 59.5%. With advantage on all rolls, the chance is 94.7%, and with disadvantage on all rolls the chance is 15.1%.

Comment: Any thoughts on why this gives a result ten percentage-points below the other answer?

Comment: @nitsua60 I haven't checked the other answer completely, but it's likely the other answer double counts some ways to survive dropping to 0 HP, since the first few paragraphs seem correct.

Comment: @nitsua60 Turns out I had a typo in my code when I initially computed it. (The code in the answer was correct, but the numbers were wrong). The answer comes out to the same as jonny's comment on the other answer.